# jquery redirect on keydown is not working

Tags: jquery, events, redirect, keyboard

So i am trying to redirect users from the homepage to the forums with a keyboard event,
This is the current code that does not seem to be working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").keydown(function(e){
            var key = e.keyCode;

            if (key == 13){
                window.location.href = "forums";
            }
        }); 
    });
```

The homepage is on the site root, as well as the forums folder.
The console is clean, no errors, no alerts...
All suggestions and comments are more than welcome and appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is forum an HTML File?

If yes, it would be important to add the extension or the complete path.

> /views/Forums/forums.html

Also, make sure that, if you use the different numeral values for the key, to be sure that the number is the one you are really looking for. You can find a list of the values [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Comment: It is a folder, i just added that detail to the question, thanks for your input though:)

Comment: It would be important to link to a specific file. If I'm not mistaken that function takes a whole URL, file included.

Comment: Can you print something inside your condition?

Comment: no, it turns out the problem is that the space bar is not being recongized, but this same code is working without the redirect on another page...

Comment: Nevermind,i messed up the key code, its suppose to be 32 not 13, my bad! Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: It may not be the case, but one of the good things to do when using the arrows or keyboard in general in web app, is to use the preventDefault, which will make your event cancel the default action that the key would have caused, for example, Arrows that scroll the page. Using the preventDefault will only execute your own action without scrolling.

Edit : No problem haha!

Comment: you can add the key change to your answer, so that people that come with the same prob know the right answer